# custom default avatar showing broken link

Tags: customization, avatar, gravatar

I am using the follow function to create a custom default avatar for users who comment and do not have a gravatar setup.

```
 if(!function_exists('custom_avatar')){
    function custom_avatar($avatar_defaults){
        $new_default_icon = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/VR-default-avatar.png';
        $avatar_defaults[$new_default_icon] = 'VR Custom Avatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
    add_filter('avatar_defaults','custom_avatar');
 }
```

and when I go to the admin panel under settings --> discussion it shows the new line with the text VR custom avatar, but the link to the image is broken.  Also when I select and save and then go to the blog the default image is also a broken image.  I went to google chrome and did an inspection on the broken image and it shows:

```
<img alt="" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/25c562d0eebef3b375ae2d0fea8ad716?s=32&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.violet-rain.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fartificer%2Fimages%2FVR-default-avatar.png%3Fs%3D32&amp;r=G&amp;forcedefault=1" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32">
```

What am I doing wrong that it is pulling from the gravatar website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `http://www.violet-rain.com/wp-content/themes/artificer/images/VR-default-avatar.png` produces 404. You probably meant `artificer-child` ([working link](http://www.violet-rain.com/wp-content/themes/artificer-child/images/VR-default-avatar.png)) which would be in stylesheet (child theme) directory, not template (parent theme) directory.

Comment: traded out get_bloginfo('template_directory') for get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and it worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: So if you use a custom avatar which results in a 404 link, WordPress tries to load one from gravatar.com? I only ask because I have a site behind a htaccess password at the moment and the custom gravatar is not loading, even though I've triple checked the URL (and tried get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and get_template_directory_uri() )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use `get_avatar()`?

```
get_avatar(
    $comment,
    50,
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/VR-default-avatar.png'
);
```

Though it won't create any addition user choosable avatar in settings, but will do the trick.